# How do you clear formatting in Outlook for Mac 2011

Tags: mac, formatting, microsoft-outlook-2011

I've been googling for how to do this for over 10 minutes.  I can't figure out how to clear formatting in Outlook for Mac 2011.  Is there a menu option or a keyboard shortcut to do this?

Answer (score 2):

try the command "paste and match style" its in the "edit" menu on the very top of the screen.

keyboard shortcut Command + Option + Shift + V (though you can change that)

Answer (score 1):

I am also using Mac Outlook 2011. This is exactly what you need to do to remove formatting:

(I am assuming that the users have few lines of text which have the desired format & few lines of text which does not have the desired format.)

1. Cut the lines of text which does not have the desired format(CMND+X).
2. Focus the cursor wherever these lines need to be pasted.
3. Use 'Shift-Opt-Command-V' or select "Paste and Match Style" from the 'Edit' menu drop-down.
   Finally, you get to see the lines of text without formatting in the mail.

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Comment: Yes, even I saw. But let me tell you frankly the steps are not detailed. And I had to do lot of circus myself to get to know, how to achieve it. So, I shared this answer. So, others can easily achieve what they are trying to do.

Comment: I think this is a better answer. Just saying "use paste and match style" begs the question: what if I already pasted?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Mac 2011 Outlook and found the best way use Shift-Opt-Command-V (or "Paste and Match Style" from pull down. But make sure you're in a spot in your email body that doesn't have formatting.

Lame that there is no 'remove formatting' button.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option is to cut the text into the clipboard, paste it into a plain-text TextEdit window, then paste it back.

Answer (score -2):

You can clear the styles, text effects, and font formatting from text in an email message. This includes content copied from another source, such as a webpage, a document, or another email message.

Select the text.

On the Message tab, in the Basic Text group, click Clear Formatting.
[Article](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Clear-formatting-from-text-22aa37bb-e818-4f1d-ac08-51f76619d3fa)

Comment: I don't see the "Basic Text" group.  Can you show me a screenshot?

Comment: I tried to, I just don't have karma yet here is the article I found. Updating now.

Comment: Ah I saw this.  I literally don't have these buttons.  Any idea why?

Comment: I don't know I think you can customize items on your toolbar. Perhaps you accidentally removed it?

Comment: @christian7000 - Are you sure this article works for Mac? I don't have the buttons either.

Comment: That article is for Outlook 2010 -- not Outlook Mac. Normally I'd downvote because you didn't answer the question, but your karma is so low...